# Simulate a real UDP application and measure traffic load on OMNeT++

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, simulation, omnet++

So I am experimenting with OMNeT++ and I have created a DataCenter with Fat Tree topology. Now I want to observe how a UDP application works in (as-real-as it gets) conditions. I have used the INET Framework and implemented the VideoStream Client-Server application.

So my question is that:

My network seems to work perfectly and I don't want to. I want to measure the datarate received by the client and compare it to the server's broadcast datarate. But even though I put much traffic into the network (several UDP and TCP applications) the datarate received is exactly the same as the datarate broadcasted and I am guessing in real conditions this traffic load is expected to vary in such highly dynamic enviroments. So how can I achieve the right conditions on OMNeT++ to simulate a real communication (maybe with packet losses and queuing time etc.) so I can measures these traffic loads?

There is the .ini file used:

```
[Config UDPStreamMultiple]


**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[1].vms[2].numUdpApps = 1
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[1].vms[2].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[1].vms[2].udpApp[0].localPort = 1000
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[1].vms[2].udpApp[0].sendInterval = 1s
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[1].vms[2].udpApp[0].packetLen = 20480B
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[1].vms[2].udpApp[0].videoSize = 512000B

**.Pod[3].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].numUdpApps = 1
**.Pod[3].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"
**.Pod[3].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].localPort = 1000
**.Pod[3].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].sendInterval = 1s
**.Pod[3].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].packetLen = 2048B
**.Pod[3].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].videoSize = 51200B


**.Pod[0].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].numUdpApps = 1
**.Pod[0].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
**.Pod[0].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].serverAddress = "20.0.0.47"
**.Pod[0].racks[0].servers[0].vms[0].udpApp[0].serverPort = 1000


**.Pod[1].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].numUdpApps = 1
**.Pod[1].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
**.Pod[1].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].serverAddress = "20.0.0.49"
**.Pod[1].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].serverPort = 1000

**.Pod[2].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].numUdpApps = 1
**.Pod[2].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
**.Pod[2].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].serverAddress = "20.0.0.49"
**.Pod[2].racks[0].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].serverPort = 1000

**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[0].vms[1].numUdpApps = 1
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].serverAddress = "20.0.0.49"
**.Pod[2].racks[1].servers[0].vms[1].udpApp[0].serverPort = 1000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your model? What type of additional UDP and TCP applications did you use? How they were configured? How did you measure datarate? Could you add the content of `ned` and `ini` files of your model?

Comment: @Jerzy All the UDP and TCP applications used is from the INET Framework (Version 2.6).  I configure multiple UDP and TCP connections among the modules. All the modules are either simple modules extending the StandardHost and the Router provided from INET Framework, or compound modules with these parts. Now about the datarate, at the moment while the simulation runs I monitor the events at a module about the received packets and check the vector graphs and histograms that OMNeT is keeping by itself, and all I see is the intervals between received messages is the same as the intervals sent.

Comment: In which module do you monitor received packets - in networkLayer module or in tcp/udp app module? Do you use statistics/scalars/vector from INET? Which onses? Quite honestly, without details about configuration of your model and configuration of your TCP/UDP application it is very difficult for everyone to help you.

Comment: @JerzyD. I edited the post so that you can see the .ini part it is used

Comment: @JerzyD. Yes all of these. I have a two StandardHost communicating and in the network layers in the udp app modules I am monitoring the events of received packages and then I use the vectors created to see the datarate.

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of research, thinking and tests I managed to achieve my desired goal. What I did is this:

Because the whole topology of the Datacenter is built that way so it will reduce the load that the routers have and balance the traffic, to take the necessary measures I created a smaller network. Just simple 3 nodes (StandardHost) from the INET Framework and a simple UDP Application that goes from node A to node B through midHost (e.g nodeA ---> midHost ---> nodeB). In the .ini file there should be a couple of commands like:

```
**.ppp[*].queueType = "DropTailQueue"
**.ppp[*].queue.frameCapacity = 50
**.ppp[*].numOutputHooks = 1
**.ppp[*].outputHook[*].typename = "ThruputMeter"
```

These commands are managing the links between the nodes and can be scaled according to someone needs (adjust the frame capacity maybe or the queue type). By making this small network you can easily customize it and take the metrics you need. I hope I can help anyone who wanted to do the same to get some feel about how to do it.