# How to change datarate of a channel during simulation in INET4?

Tags: omnet++

I'm looking for TCP behavior via INET4. I'd like to know whether there's a way to change the data rate while the TCP simulation is running? As we have this parameters in the ned file of INET->example->tcpwindowscale:

```
//
// author: Thomas Reschka
//

 package inet.examples.inet.tcpwindowscale;

 import inet.common.misc.ThruputMeteringChannel;
 import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
 import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;


 network tcpwindowscale
 {
parameters:
types:
    channel LFNPath extends ThruputMeteringChannel
    {
        parameters:
            datarate = 10Mbps;
            delay = 900s;
            per = 0;
            ber = 0.00000001;
            thruputDisplayFormat = default("p b u");
    }
submodules:
    client: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=250,100");
        gates:
            pppg[1];
    }
    server: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=400,100;i=device/server");
        gates:
            pppg[1];
    }
    configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
        @display("p=100,100;is=s");
    }
connections:
    client.pppg[0] <--> LFNPath <--> server.pppg[0];
   }
```

Now Here I want change the data rate during simulation from 1Mbps to 10Mbps for every 10sec. So every 10sec the data rate change and pick random value and run for 100s. Total of 10 values it pick randomly of datarate.

Comment: Hi. Please look for similar Q & A at this forum. One similar post is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31826970/7215379. How do you set the datarate? Better share the content of .ned or .ini files?

Comment: I have to vary the datarate of channel during the simulation.

Comment: @pasha I did some changes

Comment: @Nifty: 1) Could you edit your question and add the content of NED as a text? 2) How the datarate should vary during simulation, e.g. if simulation lasts 100 s - when and how the datarate should change?

Comment: @JerzyD. kindly have a look.

Comment: From OMNET++ Manual : https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cDatarateChannel.html The method handleParameterChange() can be used. This method is called by the simulation kernel to notify the module or channel that the value of an existing parameter has changed. Redefining this method allows simple modules and channels to be react on parameter changes, for example by re-reading the value. Upvote if it helps.

Comment: What I understand, is I should have to redefine this member function in C++ code everytime when I need it? If yes then what would be the best place to redefine it in TCP code? Thank you

Comment: Could you tell me if Scenario Scripting would be a better option for this problem?

Comment: @Nifty scenario scripting advantage: no recompile needed.